# Extract the embedding from a specific layer of MarianModel

Tags: transformer, machine-translation, huggingface

I am using using [MarianModel](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/marian#transformers.MarianModel) from the hub of HuggingFace for a translation task. Now I want to extract the embedding from the output of the last `MarianEncoderLayer` layer. Specifically, given a text, I want to get the middle embedding of the text for another task. Here is what I did:

```
text = 'hello how are you?'
inputs = tokenizer(text,max_length=512,truncation=True,return_tensors='pt',padding=True)
model.model.encoder.layers[5](**inputs)
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dohuut\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_ids'
```

What is the proper way to extract this embedding?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing discrete tokens as input to an attention layer that expects vectors of real numbers as inputs. The error you are getting tells you that the layer does not expect an input parameter called `input_ids`, which is what you are giving to it.

Instead, you could use the whole model, passing `output_hidden_states=True` as a parameter (see [the documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/marian#transformers.MarianModel.forward.output_hidden_states)). Then, you could extract the output layer you want from the obtained hidden states (`encoder_hidden_states`).

The structure of `encoder_hidden_states` is described in the documentation:

> **encoder_hidden_states** (`tuple(torch.FloatTensor)`, optional, returned when `output_hidden_states=True` is passed or when `config.output_hidden_states=True`) — Tuple of `torch.FloatTensor` (one for the output of the embeddings, if the model has an embedding layer, + one for the output of each layer) of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)`.
>
> Hidden-states of the encoder at the output of each layer plus the optional initial embedding outputs.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and now got the model output with: 
`outputs = model(input_ids=inputs.input_ids, decoder_input_ids=decoder_inputs.input_ids, output_hidden_states=True)`.
And I notice that `outputs.encoder_hidden_states` is a tuple of 7 elements, each element has shape [1,6,512]. Why it's 7? I thought it's 6 because the model comprises of 6 encoder layers?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, there is one tensor for the output of the embedding layer and one tensor per layer

Comment: Please, consider marking the answer as correct.